# What is the shortest length of an Egyptian fraction expansion for a given $p/q$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, sequences-and-series

An Egyptian fraction expansion is a sum of reciprocals of integers, for example:

$$\frac{4}{17} = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{29} + \frac{1}{1233} + \frac{1}{3039345}$$

Every positive rational number $p/q$ has such an expansion, although it is not unique:

$$\frac{4}{17} = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{510}$$

Let $\ell(p/q)$ = the number of terms in a minimal (i.e. fewest terms) Egyptian fraction expansion of $p/q$.

Given a positive rational $p/q$, how can we compute $\ell(p/q)$?

Comment: One can use standard shortest path algorithms from computer science in conjunction with upper bounds on the smallest denominator appearing to get some computational approach. Do you seek a faster one?

Comment: What are you pathing over? And how do you get the upper bounds?

Comment: For the second question, look at Robert Israel's answer. I would view it as a paths in rational numbers starting at 0 and ending at $p/q$.

Comment: So you are basically proposing the same thing as Robert Israel's answer?

Comment: Yes, except one can do a little faster than the naive recursive algorithm by storing data on ratios already searched and by choosing a good heuristic to determine where to search first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an expansion with $k$ terms, one of the denominators is at most $kq/p$.  So to check whether there is an expansion with at most $k$ terms: for each $m$ from $\lceil q/p \rceil$ to $\lfloor kq/p \rfloor$, check recursively whether $p/q - 1/m$ has an expansion with at most $k-1$ terms.

Whether there is a polynomial-time algorithm is, I think, an open question.

Comment: Indeed, I think determining just whether there exists a $2$-term Egyptian fraction for $p/q$ is essentially equivalent to factoring the denomator $q$, for which we know no polynomial-time algorithm.